# Can a star visually look like a black hole?

Tags: visible-light, black-holes, astrophysics, stars

Amateur question incoming so please bear with me.

**Assumptions**

If a black hole is born from a star going supernova, intuitively it should have the same or less mass compared to the star.

Black holes visually appear black because light cannot escape them due to their mass.

**Questions**

1. Wouldn't that imply that the light should not be able to escape the original star? Creating a black star that is visually indistinguishable from a black hole?
2. If so, would it also mean that all stars capable of becoming black holes are themselves black stars before going supernova?

Comment: You are missing one thing. It is not due to their mass. You need to look at mass in a region.  Squeeze mount everest down to the size of a proton and you probably also have a (tiny) black hole.

Comment: @Hennes that does make a lot of sense!